# Is there an equivalent in C++ to LINQ with respect to DataTables?

Tags: c#, c++, linq

Is there an equivalent in C++ to LINQ with respect to DataTables?

Comment: Poss dup: [Is there a LINQ library for C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232222/is-there-a-linq-library-for-c).

Comment: Agree. But its a 2-3 year old post. Has nothing changed since then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this
[linq-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643734/how-to-use-linq-in-c-cli-in-vs-2010-net-4-0)
 but, imho, best way to use [boolinq](http://code.google.com/p/boolinq/)

for example

```
struct Man
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

Man src[] =
{
    {"Kevin",14},
    {"Anton",18},
    {"Agata",17},
    {"Terra",20},
    {"Layer",15},
};

auto dst = from(src).where(  [](const Man & man){return man.age < 18;})
                .orderBy([](const Man & man){return man.age;})
                .select( [](const Man & man){return man.name;})
                .toVector();
```