# How to implement First and FirstOrDefault for boolinq?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linq, c++11

I there [boolinq](https://code.google.com/p/boolinq/) - grate opensource LINQ C++ implementation compatable with vs2010. I like its syntax - it looks as close to C# as it gets (from a short look [at all other VS2010 LINQ C++ implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232222/is-there-a-linq-library-for-c)). Yet it really has some base LINQ functions missing. I wonder how can be implemented `.First(lambda expression)` or `.FirstOrDefault(lambda expression)` support into it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the c++ vectors have the `front()` and the `empty()` method, you just have to do the following:

- for the `.First(lambda)`, you just need to check `.Where(lambda).ToVector().empty()`. If it is true throw an exception, otherwise return `.Where(lambda).ToVector().front()`
- for the `.FirstOrDefault(lambda)`, you just need to check `.Where(lambda).ToVector().empty()`. If it is true return the default value, otherwise return `.Where(lambda).ToVector().front()`