# How to use SQL syntax to query Visual C++/C# datastructures

Tags: c#, sql, visual-c++, orm

Is there a library which exposes interfaces which can be implemented by a native c++ application which would then allow querying the internal objects(classes and objects) using an SQL like syntax

Kind of like the openaccess sdk by progress but opensource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a LINQ library for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232222/is-there-a-linq-library-for-c)

Answer (score 0):

C# features extension methods and lambda expressions.
Example:

```
var scott = from e in employees
where e.name == "Scott"
select e;
```

`IEnumerable<T>` uses 98% LINQ, it exposes interfaces.
Just a FYI, a simple 'var' word has some power to work with any datatype.
Once you get LINQ going, consider lambda expressions to reduce code lines and more fluid experience. Good luck.